# Can I disable timer jobs for specific web applications?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm getting errors with 3 specific timer jobs which look like they belong to a specific web application (due to the name of the timer job). Is it possible to disable the timer job on the web applications on which I'm getting errors on? I'm not sure I need these timer jobs running on any other web application except for the web application on which it should be running on.

These are the errors:

**Running on Web Application - SearchCenter - 8080**

```
Job Title               R2ManagerEscalation
Server                  SPSERVERAPPS
Web Application SearchCenter - 8080
Content Database        SearchCenter_Content_DB
Status                  Failed
Completed               3/17/2017 11:05 AM
Duration (hh:mm:ss)     0:00:00
Error Message           Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Running on Web Application - SITE - 80**

```
Job Title               R2RefreshData
Server                  SPSERVER
Web Application SITE - 80
Content Database        SP_Content_DB2
Status                  Failed
Completed               3/17/2017 11:05 AM
Duration (hh:mm:ss)     0:00:00
Error Message           Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The Job Title of the Timer Job is R2RefreshData and R2ManagerEscalation. We have a Web Application called R2Workflow which I believe the Timer jobs should only run on that web application.

Is there a need for a Timer Job to run on all Web Applications on the Sharepoint server? Is this the default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that these are custom timer jobs, and given that they appear to have been written to be WebApp specific rather than WebApp agnostic, I would say they could be disabled for the other web apps, HOWEVER, it's always best to figure out why they are failing rather than simply sitting them down. 
This is default behavior for all Microsoft out of the box timer jobs, but those have all been designed to be WebApp agnostic. 
Since these timer jobs are custom, it's possible that they were written in house. If that's the case, get with the developer to see what the impact of turning them off on other WebApps would be. If the develops is unsure, they should be able to add debug functionality and test in DEV to figure out why it's failing.

Comment: Is there any troubleshooting I can do from my end just so I have as much information as I can get? I was not here when the R2 web application was implemented but I see 3 timer jobs that started failing about 3 weeks ago and they are creating entries in my event viewer like every 5 minutes or whenever the Timer Job is scheduled to run.

Comment: If they only recently started failing, then it would mean they worked before. Something changed to have them start failing. Looking at the error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", it is likely that something was deleted from the web apps which caused them to fail. Someone could have been doing some "cleanup" not realizing the consequences.